# Creating a program that will keep track of my schedule

Tags: python, python-3.x, countdown

I'm currently working on a project to make a chat bot that would make my life a little bit easier. One of the features that i'm working on is to make it help me with my schedule, and I would write "!cal" (! is my prefix).

And it would return something like, "You have a meeting coming up in 45 minutes". I know how to make a countdown to a said date or time, but not how to make it 'remember' my whole schedule. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a data structure such as a dictionary for this chatbot.

```
cal = {}

def addEvent(event, time, length): #time is a datetime
    cal[time] = [event, length]
```

The dictionary will store your events with the times as indices. You can access the events at a specific time, sort the calendar and query for the closest upcoming event, automatically delete events that have already passed, query for a time and see if there are any conflicts, or honestly do just about anything you would need.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this on reddit the other day, maybe it will give you a direction to go in. There is an open source chatbot that could provide a strong foundation for you, and maybe some collaborators.[Here is the reddit post.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/6ghvjo/i_am_a_self_taught_programmer_developed_my_very/) And [here is the GitHub.io page.](https://slapbot.github.io)